# Supporting same custom domain in two apps on branch.io on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, branch.io

I have two apps both which work create short universal links via branch.io.
Both these app support the same custom domain izx.to now the problem is if I share a url which was created from A and someone has both the apps installed then always app B is opened which is first in the app-site-association file. How can I open the app which created the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch here: if you are using the same Branch key for both apps, then this is expected. The Universal Links standard *can* accommodate multiple apps on the same domain, but it requires extra configuration steps that are not built into the Branch platform. Our system assumes every app should have a unique link domain, so installing multiple apps on the same device that use a single domain for Universal Links will cause unexpected behavior.

<s>If you are using *different* Branch keys (but both configured to use the same custom domain), this possibly might work. That's an edge case our system does not officially support, but since each key will append a different four-character suffix to the link (e.g., izx.to/`Wh3K`), you should be able to achieve this.</s> **EDIT**: this is not correct.

Comment: My custom domain is ixi.to and if you look at the app site association file on it you will see both the apps have the same "paths":["NOT /e/*","*","/"]  value. So I don't think iOS knows which app to open when both are installed as 4character suffix does not come into picture anywhere. In such cases it just opens the first app. So I don't think it will work.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right. It looks like we fixed that loophole at some point recently. You'll need to use different domains for each app, if you believe it is likely a user might have both installed. Perhaps `travel.ixi.to` and `trains.ixi.to`?